# Does delete this makes sense in JS?

Tags: javascript

I understand:

```
var obj = {
  foo: 'bar'
};

delete obj.foo;
```

removes the pair key/value `foo`/`'bar'` to the `obj` object. Or said differently, it releases the reference to the content `'bar'` to the object (meaning it will be garbage collected at some point).

I can also write:

```
delete obj;
```

as behind the scene it goes like:

```
delete window.obj;
```

leaving `window` without its reference to `obj`.

I'm not fully aware of how the `this` keyword works in JS, but my view is that it is an object that is binded to a method execution.

But I'm not sure it makes sense to write:

```
delete this;
```

- From which object does the reference is removed?
- What happens if I call `return this;` afterwards, it will be `null`?

---

Especially I'm trying to destroy an object built with `new`:

```
function MyClass() = {
  return this;
};

MyClass.prototype.destroy = function() {
  delete this;
};

var myInstance = new MyClass();
myInstance.destroy();
```

Is `myInstance` really deleted? Is all the memory freed?

Thanks

Comment: why do you try to do that at all? What kind of problem do you try to solve? Garbage collector works *automatically* in 99% of the cases

Comment: This code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @DanLowe Doesn't compile? What?

Comment: `function MyClass() = { }` is not valid, it throws SyntaxError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can also write:
>
> ```
> delete obj;
> ```
>
> as behind the scene it goes like:
>
> ```
> delete window.obj;
> ```

No, you can't, and no it doesn't. It does nothing.

```js
  var obj = {
    foo: 'bar'
  };
  delete obj;
  console.log(obj);
```

> But I'm not sure it makes sense to write:
>
> ```
> delete this;
> ```

That also does nothing.

```js
function foo() {
  delete this;
  console.log(this);
}

var bar = {
  foo: foo
};

bar.foo();
```

`delete` only deletes properties from objects.

Answer (score 5):

> Is `myInstance` really deleted? Is all the memory freed?

No. [That's what `delete` never did.](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

> From which object does the reference is removed?

It is not. The `this` keyword is not a property reference - it works quite like a literal instead. The construct makes as much sense a `delete 0` does.

Similarly, local variables are no property references; and in strict mode you would get an exception when you try to `delete` them. I wonder why `delete this` doesn't throw as well.